# cyclate an array to polulate UL - LI

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to walk through an array to populate a UL - LI structure.

My array is like this:

```
$mynewarray=array(
                        0=>_("Pro"),
                        1=>_("Stunt"),
                        2=>_("Donated"),
                        3=>_("Lead"),
                        );
```

My ul - li structure is like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdown-header" style="cursor:pointer;"><?=_('aaaaa')?></li>
    <li><a class="xxx" style="cursor:pointer;" value="myvalue"><?=_('Promo')?></a></li>
    <li><a class="xxx" style="cursor:pointer;" value="myvalue"><?=_('Stunt')?></a></li>
    <li><a class="xxx" style="cursor:pointer;" value="myvalue"><?=_('Donated')?></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I use the `foreach` function to populate my `li` list to get a structure like this?

```
 <li><a class="xxx" style="cursor:pointer;" value="myvalue" type="ARRAY POSITION"> ARRAY FIELD</a></li>
```

For Ex:

```
<li><a class="xxx" style="cursor:pointer;" value="myvalue" type="0"> PRO</a></li>
```

Many thanks

Comment: What part of that are you stuck with? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($mynewarray as $idx => $val): ?>
      <li><a type="<?php echo $idx; ?>"> <?php echo $val; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```